# When making a chatbot using botman and larvel the botman chatframe isn't working properly

Tags: php, html, laravel, botman

The botman widget appears okay but when i open it to view the chat frame it gives error 404 inside the chat frame.

This is the part where i declare the botman widget

```
<script>
    var botmanWidget = {
        frameEndpoint:'https://www.youtube.com/'
        aboutText: 'ssdsd',
        introMessage: "✋ Hi! I'm form ItSolutionStuff.com"
        title: 'BotMan'
    };
</script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/widget.js'></script>
```

and this is the chat.html file referenced by the botmanWidget

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/assets/css/chat.min.css">
    <title>BOtMANS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script id="botmanWidget" src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/chat.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `frameEndpoint` should be an URL. So either you put in an absolute URL, f. ex. `https://your-url.com` or a relative one with forward slashes `/`, f. ex. `/config/botman/chat.html`.

You can test, if your frame page is callable by using the current domain you run your site on and append `/config/botman/chat.html`.

Comment: I edited my code like this but still it gives error 404 and i tried adding a complete URL of a site and also it didn't work @codedge
`
<script>
     var botmanWidget = {
            frameEndpoint: '/config/botman/chat.html'
            aboutText: 'ssdsd',
         introMessage: "✋ Hi! I'm form codechief.org"
     };
    </script>
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/widget.js'></script>
`

Comment: Can you please edit your post and show the example with a full URL? When the the full URL example does not work, then the URL to the `frameEndpoint` URL cannot be opened. This is not a problem of botman, but of your application.

Comment: i edited the code to open youtube but it is still not working